# Retrieve query from django ORM

Tags: python, django

I created a Company in my django app, two or more person can login with the same company. I want to show the data of one user of the company to the other user of the company.

To simplify: If user1 of a company creates an object, then it should be visible to all the users of that company

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    company_email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, default=0)
    company_phone = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.company_name

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comapany_owner')

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.user.username
class Product(models.Model):

    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    product_priceperunit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    product_owner = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_owner')
```

**Views.py**

```
@method_decorator([login_required, employee_required], name='dispatch')
class ProductsTableView(ListView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'product'
    template_name = 'packsapp/employee/employeeProductsTable.html'

    def get_queryset (self):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(product_owner=self.request.user.employee)
        return queryset
```

Here I am extracting the data by employee. How can I modify the query to give the data of all the employee of the same company ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that means that the `product_owner` of that `Product` belongs to the same company as the compnay of that employee, we can filter with:

```
@method_decorator([login_required, employee_required], name='dispatch')
class ProductsTableView(ListView):

    # ...

    def get_queryset (self):
        return Product.objects.filter(
            product_owner__company=self.request.user.employee.company
        )
```

Comment: I update the question with the Product model. actually the product is linked to the employee

Comment: @RahulSharma: did you add `__company` to the filter?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't but now when I did it works perfectly, Thanks!

Comment: but to be clear my related name is company_owner so how did it work with __company ?

Comment: @RahulSharma: the `related_name` is the name of the relation in *reverse*. Here we thus say that the company of the product owner should be the company of the employee of the user.